`Flutter run` invoke specified top-level(entry-point) function on main.dart
My main.dart has two top-level function that will invoke runApp(), each top-level runs different MaterialApp. It's possible to invoke specified top-level function when flutter run?
here's full code of main.dart:
// top-level that i want to use in `flutter run`
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void text2Image() {
  runApp(const OtherApp());
}
// default top-level 
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await P.init();
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

flutter version info:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on macOS 14.4 23E214 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 3.22.3 on channel stable at /Users/acidtar/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0850beeb2 (5 weeks ago), 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
    • Engine revision 235db911ba
    • Dart version 3.4.4
    • DevTools version 2.34.3
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

maybe flutter run with some arugment will be able to invoke different top-level function, and show different app

From the discussion in the relevant GitHub issue, specifying multiple entry points should work. Still, you need to mark all possible entry points in a single file and then add conditional logic on each native platform to handle the entry point correctly. The linked GitHub issue provides a code sample of how to do that for Android.
I suggest using Dart environment variables (--dart-define<...>) or, better, separating entry point functions into different entry point files.
To supply an environment variable, specify a --dart-define flag with the name and value of the variable. Then, inside the single entry point, you can read this variable from the environment and make a conditional app launch:

defining a variable:

flutter run --dart-define=TEXT_TO_IMAGE=true


reading a variable:

void main() async {
  const runOtherApp = bool.fromEnvironment(
    'TEXT_TO_IMAGE',
    defaultValue: false,
  );

  if (runOtherApp) {
    runApp(const OtherApp());
  } else {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await P.init();
    runApp(const MainApp());
  }
}

Environment variable definition is available for both flutter build and flutter run commands.
Once your other entry point grows and requires specific initialisation, it's best to separate entry points into separate files. The default app could stay in the main.dart file, while the alternative app can be extracted into text_to_image_main.dart (naming is up to you). Then, you can supply a -t flag with a path to the entry point file:
flutter run -t lib/text_to_image_main.dart

Running flutter CLI commands without a -t flag will launch a default (main.dart) entry point in this case.

I defined two entry functions for Swift code flutterEngine.run(withEntrypoint: "text2Image") run the different app. as your suggest, I seperated entry-point into diffent file according to this answer  by using flutterEngine.run(withEntrypoint: "textToImageMain", libraryURI: "package:package_name/text_to_image_main.dart") swift run text_to_image_main.dart textToImageMain as entry point. thx again
